# Why is using throw and return with logical AND wrong?

Tags: javascript

It appears as though the following:

```
err && throw err;
```

is not valid JS. Why is this so? My IDE (WebStorm) says:

> Expression is not an assignment or call

I'm also curious about the following:

```
err && return err;
```

The above is also not valid to my knowledge, and I'' wondering why that might be.

Comment: AFAIK throw has no return value, so it can't be used in such expression.

Comment: `throw` and `return` are statements. You can't use logical operators on operands of expression and statement... the statement `return err` does not evaluate to anything so you can't use it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must understand the difference between expressions and statements.

In JavaScript, a statement is something that does something - for example: an `if` statement which checks for a condition, or a `for` statement that loops and iterates. In this case, `throw` and `return` are considered statements because they do a certain task - throw an error or return execution and a value to the caller. (Further reading: [ECMAScript 2015 Specification, *Section 13 - Statements*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations))

On the other hand, expressions evaluate to a value, and can be substituted in any place where a value is expected, such as `1 + 2` or `foo()`. In this case, `err` is an expression because it evaluates to a value. (Further reading: [ECMAScript 2015 Specification, *Section A.2 - Expressions*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-expressions))

An expression can be used in place of a statement (expression statements), but the inverse is not true. **Statements cannot be used in place of expressions.** (Further reading: [Expressions versus statements in JavaScript](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html?m=1))

---

Now that we've got that out of the way, take a look at [the MDN documentation for logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Operator: Logical AND (`&&`)
>
> Usage: `expr && expr`
>
> Description: Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

As you can see, logical AND expects two *expressions*, evaluated to become values then converted to booleans to be operated on. Now in your example, `return` and `throw`, as mentioned earlier, are statements, meaning they are not to be used as an operand. This yields the error "Expression is not an assignment or call" - because WebStorm expects an expression, but it is not what it gets.

By specification, it makes sense that this would not work, but think about your code logically. `err && return err` - and look at the description for `&&`:

> Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

If `err` were to be converted to true, what would `return err` or `throw err` be evaluated to? It wouldn't be to anything *because it's a statement*, and thus `&&` does not work on statements.

---

Depending on what you want, you can try the following:

```
if(typeof err !== "undefined")
    return err; //or throw err;
```

This will return or throw `err` if it is defined. If the type of `err` is *not* undefined, return or throw it.

Comment: Great explanation!